# How to you zip function from python in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

How to iter over two variables, please? I am searching for something similar to python for i, j in zip(l1, l2). I would like to add something like:

```
j=0;
do for [i,j in system("ls -1 file*.dat"), system("ls -1 file_t*.dat")] { j=j+1; 
set term pngcairo size 1400,800 enhanced font "Times New Roman,22"; 
set output ''.i.'.png' ; 
p i u 1:2:3 w err ps 0 lw 2 lc rgb 'red' t ''.i, j u 1:2:3 w err ps 0 lw 2 lc rgb 'green' t ''.j}
```

Working code for just one variable:

```
j=0;
do for [i in system("ls -1 file*.dat")] { j=j+1; 
set term pngcairo size 1400,800 enhanced font "Times New Roman,22"; 
set output ''.i.'.png' ; 
p i u 1:2:3 w err ps 0 lw 2 lc rgb 'red' t ''.i}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for something like this.
Just loop your lists by the index. It will stop at the shorter list.

**Script:**

```
### loop two lists in one loop
reset session
set term pngcairo size 640,200

List1 = "abc.dat def.dat ghi.dat jkl.dat"
List2 = "mno.dat pqr.dat stu.dat vwx.dat yz.dat"

idxMin = words(List1)<words(List2) ? words(List1) : words(List2)
set key out

do for [k=1:idxMin] {
    FILE1 = word(List1,k)[1:strlen(word(List1,k))-4]  # filename without extension
    FILE2 = word(List2,k)[1:strlen(word(List2,k))-4]
    set output sprintf("%s.png",FILE1)
    plot sin(x) lc "red"  ti FILE1, \
         cos(x) lc "blue" ti FILE2
}
set output
### end of script
```

**Result:** (Output 4 different PNGs, only here merged to one PNG)

[image]